# How to maximize the mode of geometric distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

If *X* is a Geometric random variable with parameter *p*, what value of $$k \in \{1,2,...\}$$ ends up maximizing $$P (X = k) = (1 − p)^{k−1}p$$

I understand this is known as the *mode of the distribution*, however, when I try graphing this on `WolfRamAlpha`, I'm still unsure of how to systematically approach this problem.

To try and come out with a solution, I originally tried to take a ratio between $P(X = k + 1)$ & $P(X = k)$ but I am still unsure of what to make of what I got out of it. I just end up getting a ratio such as:

$$\frac{(1-p)^{k}p}{(1-p)^{k-1}p}$$

From here, I am unsure of where to go with my work. I'm also unsure *why* taking a ratio here would exactly mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1-p$ is less than $1$. When you raise numbers smaller than $1$ to a power bigger than $1$ (in this case, $k$), they get smaller; and the bigger the power $k$, the smaller they get. So you want the smallest $k$ possible, that is $k=1$ which will happen with probability $p$

If you want a numerical example, choose $p = 1/3$ and plot the resulting function of $k$ with [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%2F3*(2%2F3)%5Ex%20for%20x%20%3E%200).